# Как установить libnetfilter-queue-dev на FreeBSD?

Tags: linux, unix, freebsd

Как возможно установить `libnetfilter-queue-dev` на FreeBSD?

Хочу установить сервис [zapret](https://github.com/bol-van/zapret), но не получается на FreeBSD (на Ubuntu сел и работает).

Comment: Это не возможно. В ядре FreeBSD совершенно другой ip-стек никак не совместимый с linux. Весь код, который использует эту библиотеку придется переписать начисто с использованием средств FreeBSD